# Center multiple divs inside another div

Tags: css, html, centering

I'm trying to center 4 divs inside a bigger div with equal margin between them, and it doesn't seem to work.
I've looked at other answers and tried **margin: 0 auto** but it didn't work for me.
here's the HTML:

```
        <div id="footer_frame">
        <a href="mailto: ###" target="_blank" id="email_address">mail@gmail.com</a>
        <span id="phone">044-1234567</span>
        <div id="footer_icons">
            <div class="icon_div">
                <img src="images/youtube.png" alt="Watch our work at our YouTube page" class="icon" />
                <p>YouTube</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon_div">
                <img src="images/email.png" alt="Contact us" class="icon" />
                <p>Email</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon_div">
                <img src="images/googleplus.png" alt="Join our circle @ Google+" class="icon" />
                <p>Google+</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon_div">
                <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Join our Facebook page" class="icon" />
                <p>Facebook</p>
            </div> 
       </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    #footer_frame {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 25%;
    height: 16%;
    top: 83%;
    left: 37.5%;
    }

    #footer_icons {
        width: 90%;
        clear:both;
        margin-top:12%;
    }

        #footer_icons .icon_div {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            color: white;
        }

            #footer_icons .icon_div p {
                margin: 0.2em;
            }
```

Now it looks like this, but what I want is that the 4 icons will be centered inside the black div.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: www.getbootstrap.com ahs really nice formating styles including having things in a row equally spaced out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all four inner divs with a single DIV and then set a fixed `width` and use `margin: 0 auto` on that one.

Comment: they are already inside a single div (<div id="footer_frame">). and I tried giving it margin: 0 auto , but it doesn't work. maybe it has something to do with it being position:absolute ?

Comment: Give the `margin: 0 auto` to the `#footer_icons` div, because that's the DIV you're trying to center inside the footer

Answer (score 0):

When I do things like this I try to use flexboxes as often as possible. The above answer works perfectly but I just thought you might want to try these two options out.

```
#footerIcons{ display: inline-flex;}   .iconDiv{ display: -webkit-flexbox;   
-webkit-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-flex-align: center;
```

}

This should work. For more info visit [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox--net-25655) link. Before you try to use flexbox in your code make sure you have a ll the right vendor prefixes.